# "Some characteristic C is what distinguishes A from B"

Tags: meaning

In "some characteristic C is what distinguishes A from B", does characteristic C belongs to A but not to B, or to B but not to A?

For example:

> Imposing restrictions on the available resources is what distinguishes computational complexity from computability theory.

Comment: The word I usually use is *criterion*.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the subject matter is.  As the subject matter changes, (C) changes in distinguishing (A) or (B).
In your case, the fact that "imposing restrictions on the available resources"(C) is an action distinguishes it from being part of "computability theory"(B), so "imposing restrictions on the available resources" belongs to "computational complexity"(A)

Answer (score 1):

It can be either A or undefined, but not B.

- Fiscal purism is what distinguishes her from other candidates. (A - she has fiscal purism)
- Reputation is what distinguishes one brand from another. (undefined)
- Obesity is what distinguishes my mother from yo momma. (even with clear context of The Dozens, it sounds as if the speaker is insulting his/her own mother)

Answer (score 1):

it can probably go both ways and you can regard C as a [discriminant](http://www.wordnik.com/words/Discriminant/)

> An expression used to distinguish or
>   separate other expressions in a
>   quantity or equation.

Comment: Can it go both ways? I failed to come up with an example where B, rather than A clearly possesses C.

Comment: @Adam "imposing restrictions on the available resources is what distinguishes computational complexity from computability theory AND vice-versa" :)

Comment: Ah, you meant both ways **at once**. I think that's a fairly fringe use, but it is possible. I meant that my suspicion is that B and B alone is not possible, as per the original question.

Comment: @Adam logically, you can compare B to A first (making it A and B as per designation) - why would the ordering matter to you? I'm thinking it's a causality or you're going through an ordered set? :)

Comment: @Pageman Can you give an example sentence (following the format in Tim's question) where characteristic C belongs to B alone? I can't come up with one.

Comment: "Imposing restrictions, and by corollary, allowing restrictions; is the discriminant between computational complexity and computability theory respectively." this one allows you to distinguish between the two. You probably need an elliptical statement by splitting the two sentences to have an example that the characteristic belongs to B alone. In that case it might as well be an A.

Comment: @Pageman I would say that the use of 'respectively' changes the format of the sentence from Tim's original question. I don't think it's possible for a sentence of the form "C is what distinguishes A from B" to imply that characteristic C belongs to B alone.

Comment: @Adam you can omit "respectively" and the sentence will still work :) there's only one corollary in this sentence anyway :)

Comment: @Pageman That's still not the same format as Tim's question.

Comment: @Adam how is it not? :)

Comment: @Pageman The format of your example sentence is "C, and by corollary not-C is what distinguishes A and B". The format of Tim's question is "C is what distinguishes A from B". I am questioning whether it is possible for C to be a characteristic of B alone in a sentence of the latter format.